# Как правильно сравнить тип сущности в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, запрос

Есть классы User, Accountant и Customer который наследуют класс Person. Нужно получит все Person который на является Customer. Запрос такой:

```
Context.Person.Where(a => a.GetType() != typeof(Customer));
```

Но это даст ошибку:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Можно конечо сделать ToList() перед Where но это будет Performance проблемой. Как же правильно сравнит двух сущности ?

Comment: У вас Table Per Hierarchy? Тогда через [дискриминатор](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.1.php) В [TPT](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.2.php) и [TPC](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.3.php) вам нужно делать запрос к нужному DbSet: либо `Context.Person.Where` либо `Context.Accountant.Where` либо  `Context.Customer.Where`

Comment: @AK, Думаю нет,

Comment: Тогда вопрос стоит закрыть до момента, когда вы разберётесь как вы сами организовали код. Ответ я дал в комментариях для всех трех вариантов.

Comment: покажите схему бд + классы ваших моделей и констекста

Comment: А через linq  никак?

Comment: без подробностей смысла что то советовать нет.